# Trigonometry reference angle of radian

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given that $-2\pi≤\theta≤0$ and $\theta$ has a reference angle of $\cfrac{\pi}{6}$ , find $\theta$ if it is in the

a) 1st quadrant

b) 2nd quadrant

c) 3rd quadrant

d) 4th quadrant

I need help on this problem which i'm unfamiliar with negative in radian..

Comment: You surely have a typo in your first sentence, do you mean $-2\pi\leqslant\theta\leqslant0$ or something like that?

Comment: Is it $-2\pi \le \theta \le 2\pi$ or $-2\pi \le \theta \le \theta$ ?

Comment: sorry for the mistake, it is −2π≤θ≤0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\sin \alpha = -\sin (-\alpha) = \sin(\pi - \alpha) = -\sin(\alpha - \pi)$$
and $$\cos \alpha = \cos (-\alpha) = -\cos(\pi - \alpha) = -\cos(\alpha - \pi).$$

If you try $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and simplify the resulting formulas, you will find four angles that all have the same reference angle, $\frac{\pi}{6}$.
If you then determine the quadrant in which each angle lies, you should find you have
one angle in each quadrant.

Now your only remaining problem should be that some of the angles are not in the range
you want ($-2\pi \le \theta \le 0$). 
What happens if you add or subtract $2\pi$ from one of those angles?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
 Use the identities listed above: $$\cos(\theta+\pi)=-\cos\theta.  \\ \sin(\theta+\pi)=-\sin\theta$$

Comment: If $\alpha$ is the reference angle of $\theta$, the trigonmetric functions of $\alpha$ should be the same as those of $\theta$ except (possibly) that the sign will change (plus to minus, or minus to plus). This most surely does _not_ happen in most cases when you simply add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to an angle.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, now I understand what is meant by that. Look at my edit.

Comment: OK, that fixes the answer.